# How to FindOneAsync in MongoDbDriver

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, nosql

It turns out it's very hard to find out how! Current SO answers seem outdated.

```
var filter = Builders<MyObject>.Filter.Eq(r => r.OriginUrl, originUri.OriginalString);
var shortUrl = await _connector.ShortUrlCollection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I really would expect to have FindOneAsync method. Does above work? Or does it scan through all entries first to get one on FirstOrDefaultAsync step?

Comment: there is no such method in driver api. The provided example is expected code for this case

Answer (score 1):

`FirstOrDefaultAsync` gets the first batch of results and returns the first document. So if you filter condition matches

- only one document: only one document is loaded and returned.
- less documents than your batch size *n*: only matching documents are loaded, but only the first one is returned.
- more documents than your batch size *n*: n documents are loaded, but only the first one is returned.

If you encounter serious performance issues, you could adjust the batch size for the query in the `FindOptions` to limit the size of the first batch. This class also allows for limiting the number of results to one - at least if you use the generic version:

```
var filter = Builders<MyObject>.Filter
  .Eq(r => r.OriginUrl, originUri.OriginalString);
var options = new FindOptions<MyObject>()
{
  Limit = 1,
  // Limiting the batch size is not necessary, 
  // if you limit the number of total results to 1 
  // (less than default batch size)
  // BatchSize = 1, 
};
var shortUrl = await (await _connector.ShortUrlCollection.FindAsync(filter, options))
  .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

You can check the implementation of `FirstOrDefaultAsync` in the driver source code over at [github.com](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Core/IAsyncCursor.cs).